# Having difficulty building a form summary with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the noobish question but, I am trying to build a form summary that will populate a div (immediately) with all of the fields being used. Here is a small sample of the field: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whyEnBe/pL1apg9q/10/)**

For some reason the JS is not working as I would expect it to, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

For example, I would like it to output: "AND name: john EXCEPT number 222".

I would also like to be able click on a result to remove it, and clear the field. Thank you

```
$(".allS").change(function () {
    if ($(this).next('.textArea').not(':empty'))
    // varible to hold string
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $("#text_here").text(str);
}).change();

$('.textArea').change(function(){

    var $inputs = $('form#form :input[type="text"]'),
        result = "";

    $inputs.each(function(){
        // access the individual input as jQuery object via $(this)
        result += $(this).val()+"<br>";
    });

    // store result in some div
    $('div#text_here').text(result);
}).change();
```

Comment: There is quite a lot of mess here. What is the scope of the first `if` statement (Shouldn't it have curlies)? `:input` Is probably wrong as well.. What _EXACTLY_ are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were many mistakes in your code. I simplified it to a very short code that only does what's needed to get the output you requested. Here's the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL1apg9q/12/).

```
$(".allS, .textArea").change(function () {
    var str = '';
    if ($('#name').val().length > 0 && $('#number').val().length > 0)
        var str = $('#nameMod>option:selected').text() + ' name:' + $('#name').val() + ' ' + $('#numberMod>option:selected').text() + ' number ' + $('#number').val();

    $("#text_here").html(str);
});
```

Basically, what this does is attach a `change` event handler to both classes (`.alls, .textArea`), and when the event is triggered, both input fields are tested for any content. If this test passes, a string is composed out of all the relevant values, and the `div` content is set. If the test failed (no content), the `str` variable contains an empty string and the `div` is cleared.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Is there any way I could set it up to clear its field on click?

Comment: Which field? What click?

Comment: Lets say i type in a name and a number, but now that I see the number, I would like to remove it. Is there a way to set it up that when I click on the line "Except Number 6543", that it could clear the relevant field?

Comment: Also, is there any way this could be made into a function, so that it could work with a much larger field, where not only a few of the options are used at a time?

Comment: In order to setup a click handler for _part_ of the string, it should be made a separate element (a `span` or `li` would be good choices), but that becomes a much more complicated HTML generation mechanism. Regarding making ***IT*** a function, I'm not sure what you mean... this _IS_ a function...

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was to make it generic, in order for it to work will a form with a larger number of inputs , where not all are used at the same time. Thank you, for all of your help!

Comment: This could be done, but there has to be some well defined logic to support that. For example, a structured "naming convention" for element IDs. Suppose you had `select` elements named `LogicalType-1`, `LogicalType-2` and so on, and your `input`s were named `Value-1`, `Value-2` and so on... You could iterate all of these systematically and do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing at the code, the selector `'form#form :input[type="text"]'` looks wrong. For starters, input is not a pseudoclass. Also, attribute matching shouldn't have the quotes.

This may or may not be what you want (I think it is, from looking at your html):

```
'form#form input[type=text]'
```

Also your `<br>`'s are not working because you called `text()`. call `html()` instead.

Comment: Thanks but that didnt seem to do anything.

Comment: please add this as a comment and not as an answer as it does not answer the question

Comment: @Dhiraj How is this not an answer? Please advise.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned that the output should look like *AND name: john EXCEPT number 222*. Even though your suggestion is correct, that does not completely answer the question.

Comment: OP said the output should be "something like" that. I'm just showing him why his code didn't work.

Comment: Agreed ! But your answer does not output anything like that. Kindly read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and update your answer so that it gives a solution to the problem or leave comments